# Wifi not working on Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless

When I try to find a connection no wireless connection shows up and in additional drivers nothing shows up either.

How can I solve this?

The output of the wireless info script is:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 21 Jul 2020 17:19 CEST +0200

Booted last: 21 Jul 2020 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Lubuntu

##### lspci #############################

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 258a:6a88  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

brcmfmac              344064  0
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              704512  1 brcmfmac

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

[644 root '/etc/resolv.conf']
nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         726       1  0 17:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: Permission denied

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Wind3 HUB-2FFE49
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto | method=1

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Rome (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[brcmfmac]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/brcmfmac.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11 wireless LAN fullmac driver.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43012-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4373-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4356-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43456-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4373.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43569.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43242a.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43236b.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43143.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4371-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4366b-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4365c-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4365b-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4359-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4358-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
srcversion:     778BF165F0F08FB354FB46E
depends:        brcmutil,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           brcmfmac
vermagic:       5.4.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        4B:23:A5:59:0D:2F:CD:21:25:92:F9:B4:83:84:A3:01:81:3E:5C:19
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      29:31:DA:04:CC:5C:22:B9:4C:31:3F:CE:9C:D8:F2:2A:E3:02:4A:51:
        BB:18:F1:96:70:D1:FB:71:50:09:87:8B:73:84:3F:8E:FB:31:88:DB:
        77:14:95:C9:0F:C1:A7:C8:FC:09:61:4C:2D:32:90:65:94:87:EC:F3:
        05:26:36:A6:5C:36:19:9A:0D:E2:05:E7:0B:CB:5C:08:F2:AE:4F:5E:
        56:CA:D0:81:91:3B:F3:D6:92:A8:C7:E9:F5:D7:C6:FA:E5:44:E3:B8:
        48:07:6D:67:EC:D0:CD:7D:29:DB:28:AC:79:BF:8E:39:02:09:21:0E:
        82:F9:6C:5D:D0:91:72:B8:03:61:E4:DB:5A:AC:0C:4A:A9:E7:88:73:
        AA:53:55:0D:0D:EC:18:22:FF:DE:10:37:08:E7:1E:3F:AF:A2:4D:8C:
        51:FD:E1:AE:3D:26:75:2C:34:F5:09:C7:5F:AF:AC:60:8A:B8:00:9B:
        61:05:B2:3F:8B:FB:D3:2C:7F:0E:37:39:0C:39:DB:44:D5:40:7E:E7:
        13:14:C1:06:01:09:6A:CA:A8:49:7D:E2:65:11:42:66:92:84:6A:58:
        A0:01:80:C7:90:0B:FB:70:32:37:3D:E7:66:BB:68:AD:B7:36:2B:7D:
        17:12:3F:A5:CD:06:26:10:AF:44:3C:A5:34:09:54:AC:A4:BB:94:D2:
        47:4D:21:FF:BB:59:4A:AE:91:7C:86:F2:3A:8E:C4:EE:A0:21:73:48:
        49:78:BF:BA:26:B8:B4:A0:0C:63:18:95:BC:21:FF:52:94:82:F2:21:
        4E:64:FF:B2:86:52:B1:4F:CB:7A:8A:C1:9C:D7:0B:EA:5E:FF:63:73:
        6E:B7:F2:90:AA:23:6D:2F:6C:8D:0A:2D:0D:C7:FC:A7:05:88:75:E9:
        66:77:3D:35:3D:D3:3E:1C:11:7C:B7:16:2C:6E:C8:51:7B:AC:CA:E9:
        3C:27:93:1E:B8:94:2E:1D:ED:25:36:4F:BF:F6:46:0D:83:AF:0D:D8:
        01:4F:CE:82:55:EF:00:84:45:C5:EB:0E:59:A2:C0:68:C2:C7:E6:B2:
        A2:7B:16:E8:27:BF:05:21:F4:F4:24:D8:C8:90:A4:86:C9:C7:0F:CF:
        46:BB:84:2D:CA:D5:11:4D:6A:5C:DB:DC:FB:B0:91:9F:0D:36:C6:4B:
        35:EA:BA:B6:96:D4:A1:D6:C4:E9:11:EF:6D:9C:17:DD:CD:D3:CD:FE:
        0B:11:C2:54:BA:AA:88:6D:E4:FD:4C:2E:4D:6A:94:62:D1:DB:7C:3A:
        9C:B7:2E:5D:8A:99:3B:3A:90:85:0E:5D:13:0E:74:A2:8A:BB:D4:85:
        3E:A8:CE:FF:B9:92:CB:62:37:40:53:38
parm:           txglomsz:Maximum tx packet chain size [SDIO] (int)
parm:           debug:Level of debug output (int)
parm:           p2pon:Enable legacy p2p management functionality (int)
parm:           feature_disable:Disable features (int)
parm:           alternative_fw_path:Alternative firmware path (string)
parm:           fcmode:Mode of firmware signalled flow control (int)
parm:           roamoff:Do not use internal roaming engine (int)
parm:           iapp:Enable partial support for the obsoleted Inter-Access Point Protocol (int)

[brcmutil]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmutil/brcmutil.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11n wireless LAN driver utilities.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
srcversion:     B3F119D70FB75A37C52A13E
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           brcmutil
vermagic:       5.4.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        4B:23:A5:59:0D:2F:CD:21:25:92:F9:B4:83:84:A3:01:81:3E:5C:19
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      28:60:E0:B6:F1:04:E3:B1:49:B7:2E:BA:6C:A7:3E:5A:7A:39:C2:0D:
        2D:DF:EC:AF:13:DC:B6:AB:B4:54:98:69:47:D5:D3:5B:B7:0B:DE:42:
        D0:21:78:DD:06:A6:70:8B:1D:6B:F7:BC:98:2B:EA:E6:22:D2:0D:52:
        3A:D3:11:E4:C0:90:82:C4:06:94:92:89:F0:1F:83:62:25:30:A7:EA:
        F0:A8:32:90:F8:95:C4:E6:0D:62:8E:35:17:DC:B1:71:D3:EC:5C:AC:
        CF:CB:8B:23:AB:09:C6:BA:38:27:6E:38:1D:39:18:D5:F8:34:ED:F6:
        AC:E9:CF:C1:07:D7:5A:49:FC:02:36:98:40:0A:30:5A:FD:CB:B8:8B:
        07:66:49:A7:31:F6:69:D6:F9:1D:52:1F:13:C1:F6:8D:E4:5F:93:9C:
        58:91:04:0A:DB:F6:9A:F0:14:F8:E0:EB:47:1A:32:A8:71:48:76:55:
        86:E6:23:CC:73:21:56:6E:B8:C7:9E:A5:89:CA:AD:93:3C:E9:8D:39:
        E6:17:19:2E:56:B7:E3:68:14:07:6E:36:17:A9:07:CD:E5:DB:26:C0:
        F0:6A:CF:8E:EF:1A:9C:B0:CF:53:87:77:92:F0:6A:A4:CE:C8:7E:66:
        F7:7F:F3:46:7E:E7:D9:30:10:CB:2E:88:DA:2B:56:C0:4D:2A:A5:BF:
        8B:9B:71:31:7E:5D:13:E3:81:EA:0A:24:3E:ED:AF:72:D5:65:64:8B:
        51:13:32:EC:B3:BF:F3:E1:EB:53:A6:0B:77:18:29:0A:43:0B:38:43:
        D2:6B:01:DE:A4:F2:FA:BB:D0:D0:69:D3:B8:8B:0D:98:0B:99:9B:7D:
        5B:D1:01:08:D3:06:4E:B8:3E:50:B4:32:5C:55:F1:C7:6E:D6:0B:8C:
        08:45:57:30:71:0E:61:45:52:FB:41:9A:E9:53:C7:12:FD:CE:40:30:
        A6:42:34:CB:57:92:A2:20:6D:EF:75:C6:41:88:53:50:04:A2:37:5F:
        1A:A2:04:7C:E4:C8:AF:D8:43:31:CC:00:F0:05:45:05:99:87:92:4D:
        59:B4:2F:C2:47:DF:B9:E5:23:A8:CD:80:7C:7E:73:A9:E8:4A:2B:5C:
        42:DF:29:CC:29:5A:64:49:7C:02:22:F4:95:5A:51:C5:57:26:E3:FE:
        83:DF:30:2E:22:A8:68:AA:F6:54:4A:CA:65:CB:09:42:2D:14:4A:56:
        8C:77:8E:B2:58:24:EC:DE:77:E9:E6:09:04:AB:D1:69:71:7A:90:AD:
        DF:3B:19:31:E7:8B:24:00:92:57:A7:E5:74:89:A7:5E:E2:A9:10:89:
        32:4A:2B:1A:33:B7:D2:DB:C1:6C:58:D4

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     2369BA84B34843FE73A01F4
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        4B:23:A5:59:0D:2F:CD:21:25:92:F9:B4:83:84:A3:01:81:3E:5C:19
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      2A:8D:4A:AD:DB:25:CF:97:6B:7E:3C:71:C9:F5:27:F9:DF:E4:3A:A8:
        72:60:E5:15:24:11:46:92:D5:83:07:14:AC:0B:10:02:D8:E3:21:7E:
        B3:86:A7:00:88:1C:08:B4:AA:68:A3:88:3A:EF:5D:22:32:1C:2C:39:
        E4:32:37:33:C6:E6:92:73:E1:F1:CE:42:95:35:92:17:2A:63:0D:C1:
        2B:D2:3D:15:2C:79:2D:39:BE:72:94:60:EC:5C:CB:99:0C:D2:80:0E:
        5A:AA:14:F8:C2:11:17:9C:5E:0E:99:6B:BC:7C:79:8D:45:07:B0:DD:
        0C:1E:F5:B7:D1:E4:3F:12:13:0C:44:80:55:97:BC:05:AB:2E:5A:DF:
        58:29:57:44:7C:E7:8E:C2:A1:DE:77:03:0B:D8:0C:74:7B:B9:80:DE:
        66:92:91:1A:76:44:9B:B9:65:02:40:87:0A:C8:F8:09:AF:C5:60:6B:
        34:2B:59:3F:5B:1D:70:65:03:C8:9D:A5:45:48:4B:4E:A3:AE:7E:38:
        6A:35:2A:CD:17:21:7A:53:8B:A5:92:D5:E0:90:C2:3E:07:51:3B:A7:
        7B:9B:49:B3:25:63:30:6A:2A:54:6E:C9:C9:A2:27:64:EB:84:D5:97:
        AF:26:49:29:70:5E:B0:FC:5E:B7:F5:13:98:5B:C2:D7:58:28:5F:E9:
        57:B7:A2:2D:F1:0A:15:D5:DE:48:6B:FF:F2:4B:5E:EA:C5:D9:73:B7:
        A2:48:F9:EB:A4:F8:0C:E1:19:8D:D4:D4:CE:7C:E1:A7:6E:D6:D8:3B:
        F7:03:27:7F:F8:A8:38:2C:16:B2:F7:19:86:F5:C3:65:8B:23:8F:B2:
        52:4F:C1:A5:CE:54:58:96:B4:9B:F4:BC:0E:2B:56:FC:BD:06:40:7F:
        BD:C0:43:FB:B7:12:C0:DE:9F:F6:A1:75:DF:D6:47:72:59:B6:5F:B2:
        98:AA:CB:0D:68:3A:F9:78:43:6C:80:AD:F0:6A:CB:E6:69:7C:38:E2:
        33:53:54:86:9B:93:20:21:66:C8:8F:2F:05:10:E1:CC:4C:40:77:0A:
        83:A3:3F:B6:E9:3E:21:BF:3F:CD:56:28:65:C9:5E:BE:F8:C4:E9:80:
        85:B3:34:4B:93:C7:50:48:01:49:C5:A6:D4:5B:F9:0E:76:E7:1D:BA:
        39:E4:BA:B2:97:4D:BA:73:24:9D:76:18:EF:7A:F2:89:DF:B2:E9:8D:
        5A:33:7B:76:F3:CC:05:87:FE:D3:EF:5C:56:02:99:AC:6B:D4:45:E4:
        72:C2:29:90:DD:2F:03:41:45:34:9E:58:14:2A:F7:50:52:9D:01:67:
        C2:B7:5B:AA:67:CB:CE:34:8D:2F:58:01
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

grep: /sys/module/brcmfmac/parameters/alternative_fw_path: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/brcmfmac/parameters/debug: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/brcmfmac/parameters/roamoff: Permission denied
[brcmfmac]

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   10.102758] silead_ts i2c-MSSL1680:00: Direct firmware load for silead/mssl1680.fw failed with error -2
[   10.326397] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4343A0.hcd failed with error -2
[   10.326410] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM4343A0.hcd not found
[   10.496478] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio for chip BCM43430/0
[   10.501200] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.MEDIACOM-WinPad 11,6 FullHD- WPU11.txt failed with error -2
[   10.501261] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.txt failed with error -2
[   11.505701] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50

########## wireless info END ############
```

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` is:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your message log shows:

```
Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.txt failed with error -2
```

With a temporary working internet connection by tethering, ethernet or whatever means possible, please do:

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm
sudo wget https://github.com/armbian/firmware/raw/master/brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.txt
sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac
sudo modprobe brcmfmac
```

It may take a reboot.

Comment: The file can be downloaded using another device and put into `/lib/firmware/brcm`